# Put event loop to sleep until next event arrives

Tags: qt, swt

I need to port some java SWT code to Qt:

```
Shell shell;
while ((shell = getStatusDialogShell()) != null
                && !shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch()) {
                Display.getDefault().sleep();
    }
}
```

The call `Display.getDefault().sleep();` puts the event loop to sleep until next event arrives.
The problem i have is that i can't find how to simulate this in Qt. It looks like there is no equivalent to put the Qt event loop to sleep until next event arrives. Any ideas?

Comment: The equivalent is called "return to the event loop". ***What does that code do?*** This question looks a perfect case of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html#ProcessEventsFlag-enum) with QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents solves your issuse or combination of the two before?

Comment: This will be definitely what i need :)

Comment: It's false that every application has its own event loop. An event loop can exist in a thread, and application may have one or more threads, and these threads may have event loops. An application may have a number of event loops between 0 and the number of threads.

Comment: Removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is non-idiomatic in Qt, although it has a direct translation:

```
void MyClass::mySlot() {
  MyDialog dialog;
  ...
  if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    // code to run on dialog's acceptance
  }
}
```

It's non-idiomatic because you're re-entering the event loop, and this can give rise to all sorts of problems in the design of the rest of the code, and also at runtime.

It is preferred, then, to show a dialog, return to the main event loop, and let it handle the dialog:

```
void MyClass::mySlot() {
  auto dialog = new MyDialog{parent};
  dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
  connect(dialog, &QDialog::accepted, this, [this]{
    // code to run on dialog's acceptance
  };
  dialog->show();
}
```

Comment: could u please give me example of problem that can arise if i reenter loop?

Comment: @Krab The `exec()` can call any of your other code that is callable from event handlers, e.g. click handlers, timers, communications code. In most cases, your code is not designed to deal with that, and you'll get a host of problems because of it. Unfortunately, there are a few corner cases in Qt where you're forced to use exec to reenter the event loop. Showing custom dialogs isn't one of them - so don't.

Comment: i understand that when i reenter event loop i can expect that all event handlers that should be called in reaction to events can be called, but not sure why it should be problem

Comment: @Krab Because it might cause unbounded stack growth, for example. The event handler you're already in can be re-entered if you don't protect against it. The state of your system when you call `exec()` must be such that it's safe to reenter any event handler. Most every time I see people use `exec()` with abandon, these precautions are not taken. Moreover, they have to be documented so that maintenance doesn't break things.